# MIT AppInventor: Is there a way to send a Skype message programatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, sqlite, skype, app-inventor

I'm using MIT AppInventor. I can't find a way to send a Skype message from my application. I know that there's an intent for automated calling with Data Uri (`skype:test_username?call`). I'm wondering if that's possible using ActivityStarter. If not, any solution is accepted. Another way I've found (but not used yet) is to "steal" Skype's message history (main.db, SQLite 3 format), and add the message as pending, then replace the original database with the new one. This method uses root (that's ok, I have root), but I still can't find a way to edit the SQLite database. Any ideas?

Comment: as far as I know with App Inventor you only can start a Skype call like this http://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2skype

Comment: @Taifun Would it be possible to create a service running in background (with root permissions), something like `jackpal.androidterm` with the command `input text mymessage`, open Skype at the same time with the DataUri property set to `skype:participant1; participant2?chat&topic=Something` and after Skype has initialized, perform the command?